# Is there a standard icon/logo to 'Choose Language' in Android?

Tags: android, icons, standards

We have a requirement where the user is allowed to change the language of the app as per their convenience. To achieve this, they will have to click an image button which opens up a pop up with a list of languages. They can then set the language.

Is there a standard Android logo/icon that the user can instantly recognize that this button (image button) can be used to change the language? Our alternative is to use a standard button with text but I would prefer the cleaner and simpler icon option if there is an industry standard on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings, the icon is this:
[image: icon a] or [image: icon b]

Sources: I have a few Android devices and they all have the same icon to change the language

and by looking at a search [like this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=android%20language%20settings&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=839&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTp8eHn5HNAhWHAcAKHc4xDPIQ_AUIBygC#), you can see that this icon is consistent across devices and versions.

Edit:
It's not Android-specific, but it may be interesting to note that in 2008, Onur Mustak Cobanli designed a graphic to 'standardise the language selection icon'. In 2011 this was adapted by Farhat Datta, and looks like this:
[image: icon 3]

Source: [www.languageicon.org](http://www.languageicon.org/)

Comment: Apparently they have a new icon now but thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Link: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_language